# Scala: value returning is not a member of slick.lifted.TableQuery

Tags: sql, scala, auto-increment, slick

I`m trying to write an API using Slick (3.4.1) and Akka-Http, and i encountered a problem with database inserts. Table in question looks like this:

```
    class Orders(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int,Int,String,String)](tag,"ORDERS"){
      val orderId = column[Int]("order_id",O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
      val screeningId = column[Int]("screening_id")
      val name = column[String]("name")
      val surname = column[String]("surname")

      def * = (orderId,screeningId,name,surname)

      def screening = foreignKey("screening_id",screeningId,screenings)(_.screeningId)

    }
val orders = TableQuery[Orders]
```

As i'm processing a post request with order, i'm trying to save order to database, retrieving it's primary key. As i read in the Slick documentation, i should use returning, to get back the auto-generated id. So i wrote such method:

```
def insertOrderToBase(rep: OrderRep) = {
  val insert = (orders.returning(orders.map(_.orderId))) += (0,rep.screeningId,rep.name,rep.surname)
  Await.result(db.run(insert).result, 2.seconds)
}
```

Yet, when i build it, i get an error:

```
value returning is not a member of slick.lifted.TableQuery[....
```

Should my table class, or object storing all the classes, extend anything?

Comment: What is `orders`?  How is it definied?

Comment: Sorry, i pasted a bit to short part of code into the first section. Fixed.

Comment: Do you have the API imported? These things like `import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._` or similar?